# Supporting sockets under Delphi mobile for iOS/Android

Tags: delphi, sockets, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

I need to port out date ASTA components under Delphi XE5 Mobile, and found the ASTA is using TCustomClientSocket. It's mean I need adjust this class for supporting not only Windows sockets, but also both iOS and Android sockets.

What is the best library under the Delphi Mobile for iOS/Android for supporting native sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi ships with [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) preinstalled, which is a cross-platform socket protocol library that supports all desktop and mobile platforms that Delphi supports.  Embarcadero's own cross-platform comm technologies, like DataSnap and REST, use Indy internally.